# How to select a single anchor point on a frame in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, selections, anchor-point

I'm having trouble selecting single anchor points in InDesign. When I click a frame's anchor point with the direct selection tool (white arrow), it selects all of the frame's points. To get a single point selected, I have gotten used to click-drag selecting a single point and then clicking the point I want.

That doesn't work in documents with lots of overlapping objects, for I need to start click-dragging in 'empty' space. If I don't, InDesign will assume I want to drag the contents of the object I start click-dragging on. I could, of course, lock all those objects and then click-drag select. Sounds like a hassle, though.

Is there an easier, more direct way to just select a single anchor point in InDesign? I'm using CS6 if that is of any importance.

Comment: I don't know why your direct select tool is selecting all anchors. My InDesign CS6 direct select tool only selects one anchor when one is clicked. I think the root of your problem may be in getting your InDesign's direct select tool to exhibit default behavior.

Comment: +1 for 13ruce's comment... I don't understand this behaviour... That's what happens when you Alt-click, but if you don't press Alt, it shouldn't act this way... strange!

Comment: The root of my problem is probably that I always have the shape selected that I want to select anchor points in to, you know, *see* the anchor points I'm about to click on. Clicking such an anchor point with the white arrow leaves all of them selected instead of just the one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have nothing selected before you try to select the anchor point with the Direct Selection Tool. If you have the object already selected, you won't be able to select a single point on that object.

I usually click off the page to make sure nothing is selected and then go in to make a single selection. It's a habit at this point but I'm always clicking off the page between actions to make sure nothing is selected. This is especially helpful (or annoying) when working with the type tool.

Answer (score 2):

InDesign anchors are picky.

I do a lot of:
Click --- <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> (Unselect all) -- click -- <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> -- Click -- <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> -- Click -- <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> -- Click

You just have to keep trying.

Comment: Command-Shift-A (Unselect all) - Really wish I had taken the time to look up this shortcut within the last 15 years... Oh well, learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 1):

I think <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is what you're looking for.
*(or <kbd>Command</kbd> if you use a Mac, but should be tested)*

This combo will turn your cursor into something like this :    [image]
Then you should be able to select the desired anchor point.

If the object you want to catch is placed backwards, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click to select the object behind. Repeat if necessary. Then use the combo to catch your anchor.

[image]